# Merge figures and graphics tags

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

The tags [figures](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/figures) and [graphics](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics) have the same description on their infotab. Although the tag-info of [figures](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/figures) mentions that [graphics](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics) is a synonym, they are actually not listed as synonyms. So far, I cannot see a real difference between questions tagged with graphics and figures. Therefore, I would suggest to merge the tags [figures](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/figures) and [graphics](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics).

But I cannot yet suggest tag-synonyms or mergers with my few points.

Comment: Related note: please do not flood the front-page of the site with massive retagging of old posts.

Comment: Sorry for that, I did not know that all retags would appear as "activity" on the frontpage.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe retagging is the way to go here. Not only does it flood the front page, but it hides the problem that [figures](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/figures) and [graphics](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics) are synonyms. I also don't have the required reputation. That said, even if I did, [tag synonyms](https://academia.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) are not really being voted on so nothing is would actually change.

Comment: Except one case, my retags were adding either figures or graphics tag, were non was present before. (While retagging the exception, I realised this synonymity.)

Comment: I merged the two tags, and made them synonyms.